# Print barcode in a fiscal printer using POS for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, pos-for-.net

I am working with fiscal printer in POS for .NET.

I need to print a barcode. The only way I found was using the `DirectIO` method of `PoSCommon`.

I only can print the barcode `010803111200002801234567890` like:

```
DirectIO(0, 1075, code)
```

But I can print for example the barcode `%S0003014000097`

Also where I can find a good description of what means the parameters of `DirectIO`, because the official documentation is poor.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find documentation about how the process of print a bar code works.

In the method `DirectIO(0, 1075, code)` one can change the values to;

```
DirectIO(0, 1071, code)
```

where code must have an specific format, the result string is: 
     ***OP + TypeBarCode + ValueofBarcode***

for example if you have a barcode that is "%S0003014000097", then its format is CODE39(this is an universal format). The format CODE39 has a value type of 4.

Then the final string is "014%S0003014000097" where the first two digits are the operator.

[image]

Comment: potresti girarmi questa documentazione?